# Would 1885 Western Union really agree to hold a letter for 70 years?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In the Back to the Future trilogy, part of the plot hinges on Doc Brown convincing Western Union in 1885 to hold a letter for 70 years and then deliver it to Marty.  Is there any evidence in real life of Western Union being willing to agree to such a thing?  Did they ever offer some kind of "delayed-delivery" service?  Or was the business culture in 1885 such that corporate policies were more flexible than we are accustomed to today?

Comment: This seems like a question for the skeptics SE. *I don't know their exact rules of what is or isn't on topic - this is just my guess.

Comment: I like this answer pretty much :) ... and i would like to add that with a propper Bribe, anything is possible ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the real-world policies of Western Union

Comment: This question is on-topic because learning the historical background of a plot element helps with the enjoyment of the work by feeding the "willful suspension of disbelief"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you send a telegram, you can specify the date you want it delivered.

Western Union stopped delivering telegrams in January 2006, but their Telex network was taken over by [International Telegram](https://www.itelegram.com/). Even today, [according to their website](https://www.itelegram.com/telegram/help.asp#Can_I_schedule_delivery_for_a_later) you can order delivery of a telegram and specify a future delivery date.

Of course, Doc Brown didn't send a telegram; he sent a letter. But the logistics would be the same. If he had sent a telegram and ordered it delivered on a future date, the office would have printed (or maybe written out) the telegram and kept it until the date it needed to be delivered. I'm sure you could also schedule delivery for a letter or package the same way. Certainly it would have been unusual for the delivery date to have been 70 years in the future, but if he could get the clerk to accept it, they should be able to do it.